# The list is not filled in

Tags: c, linked-list, reverse, singly-linked-list, function-definition

I wrote a method that reverse the list, but as a result, the list remains empty. Help us understand what the problem is.

Method for reverse the list:

```
void reverseList(pLIST pL){
    pNODE pN = pL->top;
    pLIST pLReverse = createList();

    while(pN){
        pNODE pNew = malloc(sizeof(NODE));
        pNew->value = pN->value;
        if(!pLReverse->top){
            pNew->next = NULL;
            pLReverse->top = pNew;
        }
        else{
            pNew->next = pLReverse->top;
            pLReverse->top = pNew;              
        }

        pN = pN->next;
    }

    showList(pLReverse);
}
```

The structure of the list:

```
typedef struct Node{
    int value;
    struct Node * next;
} NODE, *pNODE;

typedef struct List{
    int len;
    pNODE top;
} LIST, *pLIST;
```

Method for printing a list:

```
void showList(pLIST pL){
    if(isEmpty(pL)) printf("Empty\n");
    else{
        pNODE temp = pL->top;
        printf("Length: %d\n", pL->len);
        while(temp){
            printf("Pointer: %p\tValue: %d\tNext pointer: %p\n", temp, temp->value, temp->next);
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For example, how is `createList` implemented, how is `reverseList` called and how is the original list constructed? Also, did you do any debugging so as running the program in a debugger and/or adding more debug prints to trace the program execution?

Comment: You're not incrementing `pLReverse->len`

Comment: Thank you, your comment helped, I was inattentive

Comment: @Макс There is no need to create the list as a pointer pLIST pLReverse = createList(); The function createList that I suspect returns a pointer to a dynamically allocated list does not make sense..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters it is a bad idea to introduce aliases for pointers like this

```
typedef struct List{
    int len;
    pNODE top;
} LIST, *pLIST;
```

Using such an alias you for example can not declare a pointer to constant list because this declaration

```
const pLIST list;
```

does not mean the same as

```
const struct List *list;
```

Instead it means

```
struct List * const list;
```

That is not what is required.

Taking into account this declaration

```
pLIST pLReverse = createList();
```

it seems that you are allocating lists dynamically. There is no need to do so. Lists can be declared as objects with the automatic storage duration.

The function `reverseList` should reverse the passed to it list itself not create a new list within the function. Moreover you have a memory leak because the created list pointed to  by the pointer `pLReverse` is not freed.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the function `reverseList` can be defined.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node
{
    int value;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;

typedef struct List
{
    size_t len;
    Node *head;
} List;

void init( List *list )
{
    list->len = 0;
    list->head = NULL;
}

int pushFront( List *list, int value )
{
    Node *new_node = malloc( sizeof( Node ) );

    int success = new_node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        new_node->value = value;
        new_node->next = list->head;
        list->head = new_node;
        ++list->len;
    }

    return success;
}

void showList( const List *list )
{
    for ( Node *current = list->head; current != NULL; current = current->next )
    {
        printf( "%d -> ", current->value );
    }

    puts( "null" );
}

void reverseList( List *list )
{
    Node *current = list->head;
    list->head = NULL;

    while (  current != NULL )
    {
        Node *new_node = current;
        current = current->next;
        new_node->next = list->head;
        list->head = new_node;
    }
}

void freeList( List *list )
{
    while ( list->head != NULL )
    {
        Node *tmp = list->head;
        list->head = list->head->next;
        free( tmp ); 
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    List list;
    init( &list );

    const int N = 10;

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        pushFront( &list, i );
    }

    showList( &list );

    reverseList( &list );

    showList( &list );

    freeList( &list );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
9 -> 8 -> 7 -> 6 -> 5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> 0 -> null
0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> null
```